# ExtJs Set Parameters Values

Tags: extjs, coolite

I have a form with some controls (extJs and ASP) like this:

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="Countries" runat="server" .../>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" />
```

I want to send parameters using `BaseParams` of the `store` object:

```
<ext:Parameter Name="cid" Value="Ext.get('#{Countries}').getValue()" />
<ext:Parameter Name="cbv" Value="#{cb1}.dom.checked" />
```

and that became:

```
Ext.apply( options.params,{
    "cid":Ext.get('CountryCities1_Countries').getValue(),
    "cbv":Ext.get("CountryCities1_cb1").dom.checked}
);
```

as you see get the value from ASP.Net checkbox is simpler than extJs Combobox... Do you know other clean way to get the combobox value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it... Just like this:

```
<ext:ComboBox ...>
    <Listeners>
        <Select Handler=" #{myStore}.reload({ params: {cid: this.value}});" />
    </Listeners>
</ext:ComboBox>
```